# Visibility in sub-packages

Tags: package, visibility, go

How's the visibility of members from a sub-package to its root package?

This is what I mean:

```
foo          // the "root" package
foo/utils    // a sub-package
foo/tools    // another sub-package
```

Can `foo` access private members of `foo/utils` and `foo/tools` or do they act as separate, independant packages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go has no concept of sub-directories nor sub-packages. Packages are separate from each other. The import path `"foo/utils"` is just an import path (a method of *how to find the package*) - the string `"foo/utils"` has no significance other than locating the package on local disk or in the Internet.

`foo` cannot access private members of `foo/utils`.

In Go1, each directory in a source tree corresponds to a single package. More about this can be found here: [the go command](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/b4bb313b64b8ca84).